# How to automatically select screen size in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, fullscreen, glut, enumeration

I have 2 screens. 1 is 1920*1080 and 2 screen is 1024*768. When the display 2 is detect my OpenGL output should be run in that display.

I tried with glutInitWindowPostion(500,100) but when screen 2 is not detect at time output will not display in display 1. Also, I try glutFullScreen() but it's not working.

How to do?

I am using Glut library for displaying window. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Window management is not part of OpenGL, but is the responsibility of whoever creates the initial OpenGL context. You might want to add additional info to your question what library/platform is responsible for the context creation in your case to increase your chances of getting a usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a window/context management library with display enumeration support like [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/monitor_guide.html) or [SDL](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDisplayBounds).